# MorphAdorner Licensing confusion

Tags: java, licensing, legal

I want to use the [MorphAdorner library](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/morphadorner/) [available free for commercial use](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/morphadorner/licenses/). But it uses several other libraries that restrict commercial use (like Gate etc). Can I use this library in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three licenses for sub-components of the MorphAdorner library that might restrict its use in your application.

- The Gate and NGramJ libraries (contained in MorphAdorner) use the LGPL license. The LGPL effectively requires that it must be possible for a user of your application to replace those libraries (and possibly the MorphAdorner library, depending on how they are integrated into it) with different versions. Using standard dynamic linking practices should be sufficient to satisfy that requirement.
- The 'Text Segmentation' part of MorphAdorner has a 'non-profit only' type of license. If you are planning to sell your application, then you either can't use MorphAdorner or you would have to strip that component out.
- The XGTagger library uses the CeCILL license, which has similar restrictions as the LGPL.

In summary, you can use the MorphAdorner library as-is if you dynamically link to it and don't try to make a profit out of your application.

Comment: Thanks. I need their pos tagger only. But I am not sure if I can use. Can you please suggest.

Comment: @akshayb: I can't really advise you there, as I don't know the internals of the MorphAdorner library. I just looked at the licenses for its various parts, and I don't know how it is all interconnected and if you can easily pick and choose what you need.